# cant get downloadUrl after upload the image to FireBase in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-storage

after i upload my image to Firebase i cant get it's download url. i wanna get it to show uploaded pics in other pages. here is my codes:

```
  
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:firebase/GetPic.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class ImageUploadPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return ImageUploadPageState();
  }

}

class ImageUploadPageState extends State{
  TextEditingController _control= TextEditingController();
 
  File _selectedImage;
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("IMAGE UPLOAD PAGE"),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_right_alt), onPressed: (){
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context)=>GetPic(),));
          }),
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
                child: Text("Galeriden resim seçin"),
                onPressed: (){_selectImage();}),
            Expanded(
                child: _selectedImage== null ? 
Text("there is no pic"): Image.file(_selectedImage)),
            Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                child: TextFormField(
                controller: _control,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "image's name",
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.greenAccent)
                  ),
                  style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic, fontSize: 17),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
                child: Text("Upload image"),
                onPressed: (){_uploadImage();}),
          ]
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _selectImage() async {
    var _iamge= await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    _selelctedImage= _image;
    setState(() {});
  }

  Future<String> _uploadImage() async {
    _formKey.currentState.save();
    String imageFileName = _control.text;
    

    final Reference ref = await FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("deneme").child("resimler").child(imageFileName);

    UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(_selectedImage);
    var downloadUrl = await (await uploadTask.snapshot).ref.getDownloadURL();
    debugPrint(downloadUrl.toString());

    return downloadUrl.toString();
  }

}
```

i have TextFormField that gives image's name. if i upload an image(same or different) with same name i can get last one's donwload url normally. in my opinion image's name that i uploaded cant be seen at first try unlike to second try. so i am fail to get download url at first try and success at second try. i hope i could tell my problem clearly. i will be so glad if somebody helps.

Here is my android/build.gradle

```
    buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()  // Google's Maven repository
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.4.1'

    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()  // Google's Maven repository
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Here is my app/build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "meb.firebase"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.4.20"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.1.0')
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.4"
}
```

and al last Here is my error message:

```
E/flutter (17095): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_storage/object-not-found] No object exists at the desired reference.
E/flutter (17095): #0      MethodChannelReference.getDownloadURL (package:firebase_storage_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_reference.dart:57:7)
E/flutter (17095): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (17095): #1      Reference.getDownloadURL (package:firebase_storage/src/reference.dart:94:48)
E/flutter (17095): #2      ImageUploadPageState._resimYukle (package:firebase/ImageUploadPage.dart:83:61)
E/flutter (17095): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (17095): #3      ImageUploadPageState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:firebase/ImageUploadPage.dart:62:31)
E/flutter (17095): #4      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:993:19)
E/flutter (17095): #5      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:1111:38)
E/flutter (17095): #6      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:183:24)
E/flutter (17095): #7      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:598:11)
E/flutter (17095): #8      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:287:5)
E/flutter (17095): #9      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:222:7)
E/flutter (17095): #10     PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:476:9)
E/flutter (17095): #11     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:77:12)
E/flutter (17095): #12     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:122:9)
E/flutter (17095): #13     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:377:8)
E/flutter (17095): #14     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:120:18)
E/flutter (17095): #15     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:106:7)
E/flutter (17095): #16     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:358:19)
E/flutter (17095): #17     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:338:22)
E/flutter (17095): #18     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:267:11)
E/flutter (17095): #19     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:295:7)
E/flutter (17095): #20     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:240:7)
E/flutter (17095): #21     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:213:7)
E/flutter (17095): #22     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1206:13)
E/flutter (17095): #23     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
E/flutter (17095): #24     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1005:7)
E/flutter (17095): #25     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:265:10)
E/flutter (17095): #26     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:174:5)
E/flutter (17095):
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `await` the result of `putFile` to wait until the upload is complete before requesting the URL.

```
    await ref.putFile(_selectedImage);
    var downloadUrl = await ref.getDownloadURL();
    debugPrint(downloadUrl);
```

I suggest reviewing the [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/usage/) for more details.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  On Stack Overflow, it's customary to upvote and accept helpful answers as correct using the buttons to the left.

Comment: i have already tried it. When i vote as the answer is useful, getting this "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." message. thank you very much. but i can say i am able to do rest of Firebase stuffs thanks to this short solution. :)

Comment: You should be able to accept the answer as correct by using the checkmark button.